# Which is the best way to call a javascript function on a link 

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, html

I want to add some links to some website of mine, but these links will call a javascript function and will not be underlined, also I want the cursor to be changed to a standard pointer.  Which is the best way of doing it and why?

Right now I can think of two aproaches:

`<a href="javascript:someFunction()" style="text-decoration:none">LINK</a>`

or

`<span onClick="someFunction();" style="cursor: pointer;">LINK</span>`

Which one do you think is better?

Comment: hi guys, I found your input very interesting, there's some stuff I didn't think about.  As most of you're saying I'll stick to the "span" version, thanks!

Comment: If you use an anchor element the click event will be triggered via the mouse or the keyboard. If you use a span only the mouse will work. Therefore you should _not_ use a span because some users choose not to or are physically unable to use a mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this isn't really going to be a link (functionally or visually) you should stick with a `<span>` (or `<div>` if you want a block level element).

Answer (score 2):

"The HTML `<span>` tag is used for grouping and applying styles to inline elements.  When the text is hooked in a span element you can add styles to the content, or manipulate the content with for example JavaScript." -W3

"The `<a>` tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another." -W3

If you're only calling a function I would use span.

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination is better:

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">LINK</a>

$(document).ready({
    $('#myLink').click(function() { someFunction(); return false; });
});
```

If possible try putting a real URL in the `href`.  By including a real href in the link you're allowing people to either experience the javascript version of your link (such as an ajax refresh) or right click and go to the real destination.

Of course this isn't always practical, your site might require that the action only be completed through a popup dialog.  Ideally though the user should be open a link in another window/tab by following the href.

Comment: IMO worrying about people without javascript is like worrying about people without css.

Comment: Agreed - but right click open in new tab falls under the same umbrella.  Should have been clearer - might edit.

Answer (score 1):

I like v2, just because I would rather not have javascript functions in the url bar. What happens when they click the v1 link, and then bookmark?