# PHP: Trouble composing strings

Tags: php, html

I'm using this php code

```
echo " onclick='myFunction(" . $row['username'] . ")'"
```

that give me this result

```
onclick="myFunction(Francis88)"
```

But I want this:

```
onclick="myFunction('Francis88')"
```

How should I change my php code for obtain this?

Comment: Please, stop attaching event listeners in HTML.

Comment: Because you are mixing you HTML with you JavaScript. This ends up as an unmaintainable mess. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/KfBvt/) example should serve a simplified illustration of a better way. Google "event delegation" or "event bubbling" for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `\` to escape a character within a string, so for example:

```
echo " onclick=\"myFunction('" . $row['username'] . "')\""
```

Comment: This doesn't mitigate XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `json_encode()` for this to make sure it doesn't mess up with names such as O'Reilly; then, apply `htmlspecialchars()` to make sure the resulting string doesn't cause issues in HTML attributes:

```
printf(' onclick="myFunction(%s)"', 
    htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['username']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
);
```

I'm also using single quotes here, so that the HTML attribute values can be enclosed in double quotes; arguable, but I hate single quoted attributes ;-)

See also my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877485/better-way-to-call-javascript-function-in-a-tag/10877708#10877708) to find out the disadvantages of using inline JavaScript.

Comment: `echo sprintf` -> `printf` :) You should also HTML encode the data.

Comment: @deceze Good points! Fixed :)