# How to call react js function or pass arguments to react js from normal JS/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a web app where I need to do certain things in React JS. I have written the react js code.

But I want it to be called only when a button is clicked. How to do this?

I read the tutorial but still couldn't figure out this.

Please help me. Struck for 2 hours.

Comment: Do you wish to render something using react only when a button from a non React Environment is clicked?

Comment: Yes. As for I researched React is the only thing that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to render a `<ReactComponent/>` at `<div id="mountPoint"></div>` using a button click and wish to pass an Object `data` to React, this should solve your problem.

The button below is not rendered using React. There must also be a mount point specified beforehand where React will mount the `<ReactComponent/>`:

```
<button onclick=ReactRender()> Render React </button>
<div id="mountPoint"></div>
```

The button calls a function `ReactRender()` which does all the rendering.

```
//Now to render React
var ReactRender = function(){
  // data is an Object which you wish to pass to React
  ReactDOM.render(<ReactComponent data={data}></ReactComponent>, mountPoint);
}
```

The `data` you have passed from outside React will be available as `this.props.data` inside `ReactComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I am clicking a hyperlink, then is this correct?  <a href="javascript:ReactRender();">News</a>

Comment: That should work. Just make sure you call the ReactDOM.render(...) function which does all rendering for you. For your above specific question, here's the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877485/better-way-to-call-javascript-function-in-a-tag

Comment: Hi, Could you answer this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328227/how-to-resolve-uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-construct-comment-please-use-th