# How to resolve "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Comment': Please use the 'new' operat....." with respect to React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I have a home.jsp where within body

```
<body>
    <script type="text/babel" src="../resources/scripts/example.js"></script>
     <a href="javascript:Comment();">News</a>
</body>
```

In a separate example.js, I have the following

```
alert("I am coming here ... BEEP");

var Comment = React.createClass({
      loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: this.props.url,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
          }.bind(this)
        });
      },
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
      },
      componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="comment">       
            <Comment data={this.state.data} />
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}} />
          </div>
        );      
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Comment url="/workingUrl" pollInterval={2000} />,
      document.getElementById('content')
    );
```

I am getting the following error in Chrome console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Comment': Please use the 'new' 
operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

I have added React js tags in home.jsp file.

How to fix this? Please help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot call React Component `<Comment/>` by `Comment()`. The error requests you to create an instance of the `Comment` class i.e. something like this `var comment = new Comment()`. However, in your problem we do not need this.

```
<body>
  <a href="javascript:RenderComment();">News</a>
  <div id="content"> </div>
</body>
```

Your React Component `<Comment/>` should be independent and will be used as an argument to `ReactDOM.render(...)`. Hence the `Comment` should not have `ReactDOM.render(...)` function inside it. Also, the anchor element click must not call `Comment()` as it is not a function which does rendering but rather a `Class` whose `instance` is mounted on the `DOM`. On clicking the `<a/>` tag, a `RenderComment()` should be called which will in turn render the `<Comment/>` component.

```
var RenderComment = function RenderComment() {
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
                    "div", null, " ", Comment, " "
                  ), document.getElementById("content"));
};
```

Here, we are rendering your `<Comment/>` component which you defined using `React.createClass`.

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
 // Your component functions and render() method
 // No ReactDOM.render() method here
}
```

Comment: 1) So RenderComment is a normal JS function , right? If so, can I do like this
function RenderComment(){
         ReactDOM.render(<div> {Comment} </div>, document.getElementById("content"));
}

2) Also Why <div>{Comment}</div>?

Comment: Yes RenderComment() is a normal JS function. In fact, to render React, a normal JS function like this is always required. Usually it is done when the document loads. In your case, it is being done on a button click. That's the only difference.

Comment: I am getting 
VM233:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: RenderComment is not defined(anonymous function) @ VM233:1

Comment: Also please answer this 2) Also Why <div>{Comment}</div>?

Comment: Call the ReactDOM.render(...) function from within a  <script type="text/javascript" .../> not "text/babel"

Comment: The reason why I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: RenderComment is not defined(anonymous function) @ VM233:1" is because of first argument "<Comment/>" in ReactDOM.redner(...). The moment I change it as null, Uncaught .... error goes away. I tried <div>{Comment}</div> and still it throws error. 

So when page loads I get this error. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" bcas of <Comment\>. Same with <div>{Comment}</div>.

From documentation, ReactDOM.render should only be called after the composite components have been defined.

Comment: Now the question is, how to define composite component Comment, before using ReactDOM.render(.....  ?

Comment: Are you using babel to convert your JSX to JS?

Comment: Nope. Infact I don't use jsx. Just plain React JS.

Comment: <div> {Comment} </div> is JSX. I will change the answer for JS.

Comment: Warning: React.render is deprecated. Please use ReactDOM.render from require('react-dom') instead.warning @ react.js:18780newFn @ react.js:15963RenderComment @ home:1801(anonymous function) @ VM576:1

Comment: That's correct. See this link. You need both 'react' and 'react-dom' from v0.14.x. Earlier, React.render(...) was used. See this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98194/discussion-between-naisheel-verdhan-and-user3705478).

Comment: Hi, Could you answer this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126108/why-does-the-following-code-throw-uncaught-typeerror-inst-render-is-not-a-func

Answer (score 43):

Maybe this will help someone who had the same issue as me...I simply forgot to import the component I was trying to render:

```
import { Comment } from './comment'
```

Comment: Yes it did help! Interestingly, eslint didn't pick up on the missing import.

Comment: Lol, yes, this also helped me :facepalm:

Answer (score 1):

Agreed By above answer of Troy Carlson. I faced similar issue in React native project. I have used few built in component(React native) inside but didn't import it. After correctly importing all, error was gone

```
import {
    FlatList,
    SafeAreaView,
    Text,
    View,
    ...
    } from "react-native";
```