# Why do I need 'javascript:' in the call to my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Newer to javascript and trying to learn why this works, searching Google has led to no answers (although I maybe searching using the incorrect terms).

I'm am making a call to a function during an onclick event within an `<a></a>`. I was able to get the function finally working (with a suggestion from a coworker) by adding in 'javascript:' before making the function.  Without the javascript: portion in the onclick, my function was not being called upon.

It now works but I don't understand what that is doing, the other programmer who suggested putting it in the call also isn't sure what exactly it does.

Here is a simplified version of the code used:

```
#1 .jspf higher up which includes page #2 to display it's contents
function createTagging(1, 2) {
    cmCreateElementTag(1 + ", " + 2,"TagName");
}


HTML in .jspf file #2 further down website makes the call to function in file #1
<a id="CatEntry" href="https://aurl"
                onclick="javascript: createTagging('parameter1', 'parameter2');"
                title="atitle" aria-label="alabel">

                <img id="ThumbNailImage_59244" src="https://image.jpg" 
                alt="" border="0"/>

        </a>
```

-Troy

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877485/better-way-to-call-javascript-function-in-a-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I need 'javascript:' in the call to my javascript function?

You don't. It's an `onclick` handler. You use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol where a **URL** is expected (for instance, if you'd used `href` instead of `onclick`). `onclick` expects JavaScript code.

In fact, it only works because JavaScript has labelled statements, and `javascript:` is a valid label. It's completely ignored.

> Without the javascript: portion in the onclick, my function was not being called upon.

With respect, that must have been observational error. Again, in an `onclick` handler, it makes **no difference** whether you have `javascript:` in front of it or not. If it wasn't working, and then it was working, you changed something *else* at the same time you added `javascript:`.

Comment: "an onclick handler, it makes no difference whether you have javascript: in front of it or not. "

Thanks T.J. that was my understanding as well.  Perphaps I did make an additional change that I over looked.  Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 2):

`onclick` attribute is always calling javascript in HTML.

```
onclick="createTagging('parameter1', 'parameter2');"
```

It is only necessary if you use not an event, but `href`. There you need to add the protocoll as well for Javascript.